# Closest pair of point by brute force

Tags: python

I do not know what is wrong with my code. I generate 100 random points and I want to find the closest pair of these points, but the result is wrong.

```
#Closest pair
from math import sqrt
from random import randint

arr1=[]

dist=0
p1=[]
p2=[]
min1=1000
for i in range(0, 100):
    arr1.append([randint(0,100),randint(0,100)])

print(arr1)
print("\n")

def dist(a,b):
    x=pow((a[0]-b[0]),2)
    y=pow((a[1]-b[1]),2)
    return sqrt(x+y)

for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(arr1)):
    dis=dist(arr1[i],arr1[j])
    if(dis<min1):
        min1=dis
        p1=arr1[i]
        p2=arr1[j+1]

print(p1,"",p2,min1)
#print (sorted(arr1))
```

Comment: I've fixed the indentation of your code, but in future please make sure that it's correct when you post code here. Correct indentation is _vital_ in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Okey you assume that (1, 5) and (5, 1) is the same point which is correct. However while you are looping from i+1 to 100 you adding arr1[j+1] I guess this is wrong consider when j=100 and you get the closest point then you will end up with arr1[101]

Answer (score 1):

As İhsan Cemil Çiçek mentions, the main problem with your code is that you have `p2=arr1[j+1]`, which should be `p2=arr1[j]`.

However, there are a couple of things you can do to make this code more efficient.

There's no need to take the square root for every distance test. For non-negative `d1` and `d2`, if `sqrt(d1) < sqrt(d2)` then `d1 < d2`, so we can just test the squared distances, and we only need to do a single expensive square root calculation when we've found the minimum.

Python has an efficient `min` function, so there's no need to find the minimum manually. Normally, `min` does a simple comparison of the values you pass it, but you can also supply it with a key function which it will use to make the comparisons.

You can use the `combinations` function from the standard `itertools` module to produce pairs of items from your points list with a single loop. This doesn't save much time, but it's cleaner than having a double loop.

Also, it's a good idea to supply a seed value to the random number generator when developing code that produces random values. This makes it easier to test & debug your code because it makes the results reproducible.

In the code below I've increased the range of the coordinates, because with 100 points with coordinates in the range 0 to 100 there's a high chance of generating duplicate points. You might like to use a set instead of a list if you don't want duplicate points.

```
from math import sqrt
from random import seed, randint
from itertools import combinations

seed(17)

high = 1000
numpoints = 100

points = [(randint(0, high), randint(0, high)) for _ in range(numpoints)]
points.sort()
print(points, '\n')

def dist(t):
    a, b = t
    x = a[0] - b[0]
    y = a[1] - b[1]
    return x*x + y*y

t = min(combinations(points, 2), key=dist)
a, b = t
print('{} {}: {}'.format(a, b, sqrt(dist(t))))
```

**output**

```
[(9, 51), (18, 443), (19, 478), (21, 635), (27, 254), (50, 165), (52, 918), (55, 746), (70, 316), (95, 707), (112, 939), (113, 929), (126, 903), (132, 256), (143, 832), (145, 698), (154, 692), (187, 200), (197, 765), (201, 154), (203, 317), (217, 51), (244, 119), (257, 983), (258, 880), (264, 76), (273, 65), (279, 343), (296, 178), (325, 655), (326, 174), (338, 552), (340, 96), (363, 51), (368, 59), (381, 585), (383, 593), (393, 834), (411, 140), (412, 496), (419, 83), (485, 648), (491, 76), (513, 821), (519, 962), (534, 424), (539, 980), (545, 572), (549, 312), (555, 87), (564, 63), (566, 923), (568, 545), (570, 218), (577, 537), (592, 801), (618, 848), (655, 614), (673, 413), (674, 314), (677, 284), (702, 141), (702, 215), (721, 553), (732, 654), (749, 974), (762, 279), (764, 429), (766, 732), (770, 756), (771, 356), (784, 722), (789, 319), (792, 5), (805, 282), (810, 896), (821, 978), (824, 911), (826, 310), (830, 323), (831, 418), (832, 518), (836, 400), (859, 256), (862, 996), (866, 700), (879, 485), (888, 415), (903, 722), (930, 588), (931, 496), (938, 356), (942, 323), (942, 344), (948, 429), (967, 741), (980, 254), (982, 488), (982, 604), (983, 374)] 

(381, 585) (383, 593): 8.246211251235321
```

Answer (score 0):

It will only work for first point, for all other points in list you are just checking the remaining points from (i+1 to n) not all points.(closest may also be in 0 to i)

Comment: This actually isn't the case. If you did this you would just end up checking each pair twice. For example, point 0 checks distance for every point from 1 - 99. Once you then get to point 1, it has already checked distance against point 0, so it doesn't need to do it again, and the same thing happens as you go through the points

Answer (score 0):

You should use enumerate in the for loop, right now you are checking the i pair with all the pairs that appears after it in the array, what about the pairs before him?
also, you need to save the first and second pair that meet the condition of the distance as the i and j pair, why pair[j+1]?

Try this, I think it should work:

```
from math import sqrt
from random import randint
arr1=[]

dist=0
p1=[]
p2=[]
min1=1000
for i in range(0, 100):
  arr1.append([randint(0,100),randint(0,100)])

print(arr1)
print("\n")


def dist(a,b):
  x=pow((a[0]-b[0]),2)
  y=pow((a[1]-b[1]),2)
  return sqrt(x+y)


 for i,x in enumerate (arr1):
   for j,y in enumerate (arr1):
    if (x != y):
    dis=dist(arr1[i],arr1[j])
    if(dis<min1):
      min1=dis
      p1=arr1[i]
      p2=arr1[j]


print(p1,"",p2,min1)
print (sorted(arr1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.according to this code if i want to generate 10 points and find the closest pair of them .one of the result is this:[[29, 98], [34, 50], [11, 59], [87, 73], [99, 15], [8, 1], [93, 26], [53, 100], [11, 97], [1, 32]]


[99, 15]  [93, 26] 12.529964086141668       and it is right.thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: This code performs twice as many tests as necessary: for a given `i` & `j` there's no need to test both `dist(arr1[i], arr1[j])` and `dist(arr1[j], arr1[i])`, but that's effectively what your code does.